# WebView2 - How can I get the same functionality as WebBrowser.Document.OpenNew(true)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control, webview2

In System Forms Webbrowser, Below is the code to Open New HTML Document each time webrowser is updated with new HTML content

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true).Write(html);
```

In Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 I can use navigate to string like below to update HTML string.

```
webBrowser.NavigateToString(html);
```

But this doesn't open a new document. It updates on same.
Is there a way in WebView2 to set HTML content on the new document each time content is changed?

Comment: What do you mean by opening a new document? You mean a new instance of the browser?

Comment: this is OpenNew documentation  
HtmlDocument.OpenNew ->  Gets a new HtmlDocument to use with the Write(String) method.
webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true).Write(html);
In the System Form Browser example, in the same web-browser instance, it used the update with the new HTML document object whenever new HTML content is set using  opennew.write

Comment: How do you test to see if this is a new document or the same document? What will go wrong if you use NavigateToString?

Comment: In the System Form WebBrowser, When right click is performed Back and forward menus is always disabled(with OpenNew)
In WebView2, Back and forward are enabled, allows to navigate as well

Comment: What you're doing with `[Document].OpenNew(true)` is clearing the history (so you cannot *go back* after). You can do the same in WebView2 using the [CallDevToolsProtocolMethodAsync()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.calldevtoolsprotocolmethodasync) method (IIRC, using `"Network.clearBrowserCache", "{}"` as parameters, but I don't remember whether that just clears just the cache or the history, too)

Comment: "Network.clearBrowserCache", "{}" this doesn't clear the history.  Even after setting it back and the forward menu is enabled and allows navigation. [Chrome Dev Tools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-3/Network/#method-clearBrowserCache)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a javascript `document.open(type, replace)` that can help you to achieve the same functionality as the old WebBrowser control's [Document.OpenNew(replaceInHistory)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.opennew?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

To use it with WebView2, you need to call [ExecuteScriptAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.wpf.webview2.executescriptasync?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1072.54&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), for example:

```
await webView21.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
await webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync(
    "document.open('text/html', true);" +
    "document.write('<html><body>XXXXXXXXXX</body></html>');");
```

It will open a new document and replaces the history.

Comment: I have html content like below
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" >
    <style type="text/css">
    .group
    {border-style:double;}
    body
    {background-color:#D3D3D3;height:100vh;margin:0;}
    test{color:red;}
    pre{font-family:"Arial", Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
    </style>
    <body>
    <pre><div class="group">
    <span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:1.8em">Title</span>
    <test>Testing 123</test>  
    </div></pre></body></head>

for this its not workin

Comment: same content works when using WebView2.NavigateToString but not when document.write is used. changed text/html to text/css but no luck

Comment: What about WebBrowser control? Does it work when you use it like: `webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true).Write(html);`? If it works using `WebBrowser`, it will work with above solution as well.

Comment: Alright I tried it with both WebView2 and WebBrowser control and for both it works as expected. If you want to pass the HTML content, use  it like this in C#: `var writeCommand = "document.write('" + htmlContent + "');";` Also please keep in mind, all `'` characters of the htmlContent needs to be escaped to `\'`.

Comment: To easily test your HTML string, read it from a string resource or load it from file.

Comment: document.write - It works if htmlContent is in a single line. If htmlContent has line breaks(multiple lines) it doesn't work I guess.

Comment: It requires escaping new lines

Comment: You are right after replacing \r\n with \\r\\n it worked.  Back and Forward buttons in the menu were always disabled.  
Another Observation is when HTML is loaded using webBrowser1.Document.OpenNew(true).Write(html)
When refresh is performed, content is getting cleared and a blank screen is shown in webbrowser